# How to group duplicates in IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

How would I build a query like this for indexedDB:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) as ids FROM contacts GROUP BY name HAVING count(name) > 1
```

My goal is to show items that are duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to iterate manually, but use an index to iterate by names:

In your "upgradeneeded" handler:

```
// Assumes records like {id: 1234, name: 'Beyoncé'}
var store = db.createObjectStore('contacts', {keyPath: 'id'});
var index = store.createIndex('by_name', 'name');
```

To query:

```
// Results end up here - this is map from name to array-of-ids:
var dupes = new Map();

var tx = db.transaction('contacts');
var index = tx.objectStore('contacts').index('by_name');
var req = index.openCursor();
var last;
req.onsuccess = function() {
  var cursor = req.result;

  if (!cursor) return; // Done!

  var name = cursor.key, id = cursor.primaryKey;

  if (name === last) {
    // It's a duplicate!
    if (!dupes.has(name)) dupes.set(name, []);
    dupes.get(name).push(id);
  } else {
    last = name;
  }
  cursor.continue();
};
```